# Does the requests module truncate headers?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to make a POST request to my API using a fairly long (1017 chars) Bearer token for authorization.

No matter what I try, as I fire up the request I get an error saying that `\u2026` (horizontal ellipsis) in position 512 can't be encoded with the 'latin-1' encoding. Since I can't find any problem (or ellipsis) with the header I specified, my only explanation is that the requests module internally and silently truncates my token. Could that be the case? Can it be disabled? Any other workarounds?

Comment: **Did you try to check** the value that the code is trying to encode? For example, by using a debugger? Where exactly is the error occurring? **Please read** about how to create a [mre], as well as [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/); and try to show a [complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146).

Comment: you likely pasted the bearer token into your script from some place where it was truncated. Perhaps such a source might have a display of the token (trunkated) and a copy token option/button. Any chance you highlighted the token on a webpage for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not truncate the header.  You can see this by running a localhost http server that prints all received requests.  Here is an example using a 2000 character token.

```
# from https://gist.github.com/mdonkers/63e115cc0c79b4f6b8b3a6b797e485c7
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import logging

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_response(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length']) 
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length) 
        logging.info("POST request,\nPath: %s\nHeaders:\n%s\n\nBody:\n%s\n",
                str(self.path), str(self.headers), post_data.decode('utf-8'))

        self._set_response()
        self.wfile.write("POST request for {}".format(self.path).encode('utf-8'))

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    server_address = ('', 8080)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    httpd.server_close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Running this on localhost and then using requests to post a request:

```
import requests
import random
import string

token = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=2000))
requests.request('post', 'http://localhost:8080', headers={'token': token}, body='hello world')
```

results in the following output:

```
INFO:root:POST request,
Path: /
Headers:
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: python-requests/2.31.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
token: CrJlFIgJbvNdpTFPvkvCpaCPmugqMbjCUOYJaCCoibZdLfrEmLRDyxXiABGqHPTpkDYXznIWyVHwmThzBbzISh
umCnRXzQveOrSCAgfYWsfNSQDKGRvsTLnwCAWuVofumJPIhJQgQibpVJPQzqjncqjDbbHVjHidOJievmATjRexUPtVtke
zuMaifyNkPiMPJwwoofurbMJyueoKKdnDuTUxhTrryuuMSUYhoRjVIvtxtBdpIBjvrRcDFbLZtQXSBwcqpuSRWfnNMjll
xebGylOpGEqsfQJtfzkUbtJgbSvzuolDcyXvVjVTqnFakPPGRojYVBioUsllKABIjqzzZblTncrxKYjPSTgzoBIPnjcIn
WYWBsKXkRoRZbVFJnaEERnXjNTMkqGfqMDuADdGXUASRTOUsSDNcpRUzMwwWVhjQEWIpqtrDrxazIkvcoGwERSFDyUgGZ
FtAiWTkiBiwKmcFbwYkZXIJBWGvXJAVylHvMcYrgyVYycbbwabTRAbviddMQCopTZLgbriyZTMvepQOWabQaVdMRGeeZU
zOrLXiqjnulhyNWQOkOgTVVZCNTavrVnJJtBGPMDqzDvcenXziMRIQeXmvyuenZnTDgTSWSAMMPEPwHYPHKzbjLQspeeY
SETSPfgCfoGWattjpnghHJgvarBSLkwwLYfgZhjejobPXRiVZLdzIXhjXSsomeEwAsIUOgcuKBNIOuyZGZVGTeqYMhoSR
JHtfnLWJQIgyDbppALRMmZtAIrerBgNMeDueanSZmogaRNsrQVjIlWnSjqAjEWRtkdmRXoIQWkAYZniMjXOAfBDnQnUoW
uEFQRvbDxCFlwdBnjJDFYaWhHLPYDzLzZOfZtJqVEucAujDXBQhTtXXgnhSHrnCGuWsTzTDUzmKbIDaYdPTmVMDArvufd
fKXLUbriqvrJBMVoTXltcnCpqEELnnYKfgDfWgLCDHRaqJlkiZYUIANHsIrZxhFEJTpsCCwOMwaqjNQtgDDWfWseOgnwc
LUfGzQUKyayNdkwXEOCNsWoDfHGEfNatWvdNeiMTlXiztljvmXLDgJqzIwlqnkXmnVkPtsUJiJbieDYYDALTLNQNHbQjx
uiquCHQscKViGcAgVCJZqoZFhzDtuDRewTYHomvpttxoTTRePRxYoGFDIRUBcTlLhJnouqNjQgZDaPdvyWSLIxddmYYNU
bKoKVWNwfYQsFQgoVsSFSboBgIvJjkxMnifwdDqkNJAcZxQYcwhUUbDwCyYbMSNmpGYaJlxeNUlcrLWXSrzAtAfblXtnC
UzpnOJVYIsGONvdZyJIDwGdbaXsGZtILdPFTanTIhkoPUzDCjdaEslDXCqcaCwjIUKJMEiileCiIGASLyFYFLkKBHepbn
dgmzeJQqEKycchmquNLGoVTJRPPwFBBRyzoEXylieyAUihLHHulYFJIWKXayiwkqIWjPKxmHaHUWanrzMbiHaMYdubXxk
YAANJbNKvIWjZhheFMSOeIPogikXHTspixWKdFTZWWOKqsahTkFKJzrmUtBtqoYlXSjBErsbkbzJOtuXAeXHbKZsekmmU
ohgOAdwaTVJgQLsYRIzIHnhErjKYEViADXfdXncenufRJDmAkEcjpqpxmFKdQmtqKwlUskVtgBAeVwnOTxdUnucxOcdyD
uHoWAntZculQybCDYDEuqnzzjRklcGgAsNkyogLeZCRDSNWhQJCEQoiSChtAFWpmmzAjlhEDOnTzJyIUCzdbbPjhuDynk
AuCggemjZIuisiVqgtJirqrbQeFlWckKVWsjIURcpeyGhQXzcQBQraqMJgBUafQyJiCcOefBrvwJOqyARmUZnunpwkBlD
ytgwnwbBhdTUfyfUYeJjbDMDKiIYSOcyosmZvINlUYUuPhkkyojtYOzYtSFCdwTwxFJcqCDOTxyalYkvNYDvuaQKFwWIQ
fkQAXiaoDQYREuhyntQBDCJohSqcdjZntuwgOVCvOPyJYMSNzksVDx
Content-Length: 11


Body:
hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

The **requests** module in Python itself should not truncate headers.

The error you have described might be related to the encoding or handling of non-ASCII characters in your Bearer token.

You can try to print your token to the console and check the position where the error arises (and ensure the validity of the displayed token).

Also, you can try to copy and paste printed token to e.g. Notepad++ and enable special characters to check if there is some 'unreadable' character.

Alternatively, try encoding your Bearer token using 'utf-8'.

```
import requests

token = 'your_token'

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.encode('utf-8')
}

response = requests.post("your_api_endpoint", headers=headers)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried all of that. I copied the token from the browser's devtools. It looks fine to me. The location at which the error is supposed to be contains normal latin letters

Comment: could you please share the token? ( maybe change a couple of symbols from the security POV :) )
and the sample of the code around the making request.